# How can I replace sub-strings of a large string based on a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, string, replace

I have a long string (a "template") containing "replacement points" in the form of %MARK% (there can be more occurences in the string for a single given marker too). I want to replace these markers, controlled by a Python dictionary (it does not contain the % signs for markers), like:

```
rep_dict = { "TITLE": "This is my title", "CONTENT": "Here it is the content" }
```

The problem: simple call of `replace()` method one by one is not a good solution: the previous replacement may contain one of these marks, which then must not be replaced!

The solution should be fast enough, since I have large templates, and I need to replace many of them within a big loop. I have a very ugly and long implementation with many `find()`'s, counting offsets in the original string during the replacament process, etc. I have the hope that there is a much nicer, more compact, and quicker solution.

Comment: Pity you used %MARK% instead of {MARK} because you could have used conventional string formating with your dictionary. Also with ${MARK} or $MARK you could have used string templates.

Comment: @joaquin did you mean `%(MARK)` or `{MARK}`? The `%...` notation is deprecated, and the `{...}` one requires him to double plain-text curly braces: `{{these braces make it to the output string}}, {these do not}`.

Comment: No I was not refering to interpolation with `%` (btw it has no date of disappearance yet, despite what was said) but `string.Template`. I reedited and completed my comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is

```
import re
re.sub(r'%(.+?)%', lambda m: rep_dict[m.group(1)], YOUR_TEMPLATE)
```

Not fast enough? Someone said 'do not use regex' and you obey? Parsing your template using some code in Python would be even more complex and slow (don't forget, `re` is written in C).

Comment: Thanks, well, I didn't want to avoid regexps by intent (it's more like the case that I am somewhat beginner in Python) ... This is a nice and "elegant" solution, however there is a little problem with it: template may contain a marker, which is not in the rep_dict. In this case this solution produces an exception. I would need the unmodified %...% marker in the return string if there is no replacement information for that in the rep_dict.

Comment: If you want to ignore invalid markers, you should use `rep_dict.get(m.group(1), m.group())` instead of `rep_dict[m.group(1)]`. http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get

Comment: Till now, this is my best solution (with more implementation details inside):

    def __replace_by_dict(rep, s):
        s = re.split("(%[A-Z0-9_]{1,32}%)", s)
        for a, b in rep.items():
            for c in range(len(s)):
                if s[c] == "%" + a + "%":
                    s[c] = b
        return "".join(s)

It was written since I've asked the question and before I read your answer. But your solution is much more elegant, just I have problems with the "unhandled markers", as I've mentioned.

Comment: You could just catch the KeyError and `pass`

Comment: Nice, your comment helped me to understand this now. Thank you for your answer/comments!

Comment: @urschrei: does it work inside a lambda function? Since I need to have the result (just unmatched markers left as-is), if I catch exception outside of the re.sub() I will have no answer, what I need. If I don't misunderstand something here ... pyos' solution is nice, especially with his last comment.

Answer (score 0):

This was excellent. I have always used the excuse of not having time to learn RegEx,
but always respected it. This post gave me the necessary to get started. This was my solution
though, I found the group call was mixed up in the dictionary parameters:

```
retVal          = re.sub(r'%title', theTitle, template)
retVal          = re.sub(r'%([a-z]+?)+', \
                    lambda m: myDict.get(m.group(0)[1:], ''), retVal)
```

`title` was not in the dictionary, that is why I did it first. Requrements of the others in the team.